# Is there an English expression for the German phrase 'per Knopfdruck'?

Tags: phrases, expressions, translation

I want to describe a use case for an app where the user can easily generate grocery lists from his recipes. The text should be something like: 
Create grocery lists from your recipe collection
*) easily via click.
*) easily.
*) via simple click.
...

But this sounds like a one-to-one word translation. In German, I would write something like "Erstellen Sie per Knopfdruck Einkaufslisten aus Ihrer Rezeptsammlung". But "per Knopfdruck" (via clicking a button) does not necessarily mean that one click is enough to create a grocery list of a recipe collection. From a technical point of view, also two or three clicks could be needed for this use case.

Is there an English expression or phrase to describe a technical use case in an app or program, that describes that 'this use case is very easy and can be executed in very few steps'?

Comment: "At the click of a button" is a fairly common expression, and few people take it too literally.

Comment: @HotLicks Ok, thanks. Didn't know that. While doing some research at first, I thought this would be a one-to-one translation, but obviously it isn't.

Comment: Amazon famously patented *[one click purchasing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Click)*. It caused a bit of a stir in the early 2000s that they had the gall to patent such an obvious thing. But since then “one click <whatever>” has become a standard term in Startupese.

Answer (score 3):

A literal translation would be “at the touch of a button”, although, as you correctly supposed, that would only strictly apply if it was really one touch of one button. For your use case, I would suggest:

*For an app with a mouse-based UI:*

… in/with just a few clicks.

*For an app with a touch-based UI:*

… in/with just a few taps.

The variants with “in” are used slightly less frequently, and “just” is optional.

*To emphasise the speed and ease you might say:*

… in a breeze with just a few clicks/taps.

Comment: Ok, but "with a few clicks" suggests that it the use case is somewhat complicated since it needs 'several clicks' and not 'just one'. I think about using HotLicks' proposal, since he said  that this is a fairly common expression.

Comment: Yes, here it's naturally the age-old marketing question of being totally honest vs attracting customers. For what it's worth, to my ear, “at the touch of a button” sounds marginally better than “at the click of a button” — perhaps it's the matching vowels, or the fact that “touching” requires less effort than “clicking”!

Comment: @Peter I have a feeling the general saying came about before mice/mouses, referring to machines in general. Back in the day people used to say we live in a push-button world, this was most common I think in the 50s/60s. Push-button warfare also according to NGrams was most popular at around the same period. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=push-button+world%2C+push-button+warfare&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpush%20-%20button%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpush%20-%20button%20warfare%3B%2Cc0